# last tab hides behind first tab: XLPagerTabStrip

Tags: ios, swift3, xlpagertabstrip

I'm using XlPagerTabStrip for the swipe tabs, everything looks great beside the last tab hiding behind the first tab for the first time while screen is in vertical mode. But after app goes to landscape mode, everything looks good even when app is back to vertical mode.

I'll really appreciate if anyone can guide me towards right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, the problem was i copied the Button bar view which was causing the problem. later after i use UICollectionView and initialized class as ButtonBarView and module as XLPagerTabStrip, Problem fixed.